# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column material_tags.material_uuid

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I have searched for people who encountered this error but I still can't find the solution.

I have been getting the error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'material_tags.material_uuid' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tags`.*, `material_tags`.`material_uuid` as `pivot_material_uuid`, `material_tags`.`tag_uuid` as `pivot_tag_uuid` from `tags` inner join `material_tags` on `tags`.`uuid` = `material_tags`.`tag_uuid` where `material_tags`.`material_uuid` in (05a36470-d0a0-11e7-91b4-ff3d7d9f961a) and `tags`.`deleted_at` is null)"

in which if I have to view Material 05a36470-d0a0-11e7-91b4-ff3d7d9f961a it should look like this
[image]

When I try to run this code located on the controller:

```
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $material   = Material::with('tags')->where(
        'uuid',
        $id
    )->first();
```

where my Material Model has this:

```
    public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'material_tags');

}
```

So I have a Tags table where all the tags are stored, and a Materials table that has all the materials stored. and I have the Material_tags table to see what Materials have tags.

my create_materials_table at migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('materials')->create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid')
            ->primary();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('viewing_time')
            ->default(15)
            ->comment('In seconds');
        $table->text('description')
            ->nullable();
        $table->uuid('organization_id')
            ->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

my create_tags_table migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('materials')->create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid')
            ->primary();
        $table->string('name')
            ->unique();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

and my create_material_tags_table migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('materials')->create('material_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid')
            ->primary();
        $table->uuid('material_id');
        $table->uuid('tag_id');

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('material_id')
            ->references('uuid')
            ->on('materials')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')
            ->references('uuid')
            ->on('tags')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the custom foreign keys:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'material_tags', 'material_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I have been dealing with this for days. Thank you!